# Pass a point into a thread and have it modified

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to keep reference of an object passed into a thread. The way the environment is setup I must keep application specific drawing in the same thread it was initiated. So I tuck away app init code in a thread and then get a reference to a custom component I'm interested in.

This isn't working. The app loads and shows up fine but the pointer to the app in the main thread is always `null`. Even if I use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::ref`. Doesn't seem to matter what I do, the pointer is always null.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
public: 
   int value;

    SomeClass() { value = 0; }
};

void ExecuteThread(SomeClass* c) {
  c = new SomeClass();
  c->value = 555;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
SomeClass* c = nullptr;

// std::ref(c) doesn't work 
// Have also tried passing std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> 
std::thread t1 = std::thread(&ExecuteThread, c);

t1.join();

std::cout << "c: " << c << "\n";
std::cout << "c->value: " << c->value << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand what _copying a pointer_ does.  You have two `Canvas` pointers and you're only changing one of them.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I literally mention why I need to do that.
@DrewDormann it's a pointer and not a value. Even when I used `std::ref` around the pointer the problem was the same.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue without Qt at all?

Comment: @Maverick in the code you show, you have two different pointers.  Changing one does not change the other.  (Your problem is not related to Qt, but how pointers work.)  I can't comment on the bug in your code using `std::ref`, because I can not see it.

Comment: @SergeyA I wrote a test bed for the issue using a class with one member variable. Same problem. So it's not QT related. It seems std::thread copies no matter what I try to do to pass the reference to the new thread. Which is incredibly misleading as I've spent hours online looking at ways to pass pointers and share pointers online and this is what they've said to do for threads.

Comment: @DrewDormann I made a comment that I have tried wrapping the argument like so: `std::thread(&ExecuteGUI, argc, argv, std::ref(canvas));` and it did not change anything. Same problem.

Comment: If you were able to reproduce without Qt, I suggest you post short answer without Qt. To me all the Qt code is noise I can't understand, and can't comment on the essence of the issue.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov yes everyone has drilled that point home that they are copies. I've even tried using `std::ref` on the pointer and passing `std::shared_ptr<Canvas>`s with no luck.

Comment: @SergeyA ok I have written a test bed. I will edit with that code instead.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I understand the difference. I didn't know `std::thread` secretly made pointer copies and that passing an address is the way to sneak around that. This works.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I got it working so clearly I understand the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just so that people do not get confused by incorrect self-answer, I am providing my own, correct answer.

The prime issue with OPs code is the fact that passing pointer by value copies the pointer, and any modification to it will not affect the original. Threads do not change this fact, and do add nothing to it. In particular, the code can be illustrated as

```
 void change(int* k) {
      k = nullptr;
 }

 int i;
 k = &i;
 change(k);
 // k here is still the same as before calling `change`
```

If one wants to change passed **pointer**, it should be passed as a reference: `void change(int*& k)`.

Having threads here changes things slightly. Since there is no way to pass something to a `std::thread` constructor by reference, `std::ref` needs to be used. The function signature should still accept pointer by reference, and `std::ref` should be used where thread is created:

```
auto t = std::thread(change, std::ref(k))
```

Answer (score -3):

`std::thread` secretly makes copies of everything you pass as an argument **including pointer data**.  This is incredibly misleading. The only way around that is to **pass an address to a pointer** and have the thread copy *that*. Then in your thread's task, deference to a pointer.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
public: 
   int value;

    SomeClass() { value = 0; }
};

void ExecuteThread(SomeClass** c) {
  *c = new SomeClass();
  *c->value = 555;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
SomeClass* c = nullptr;

std::thread t1 = std::thread(&ExecuteThread, &c);

t1.join();

std::cout << "c: " << c << "\n";
std::cout << "c->value: " << c->value << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, there is no secret copy anywhere. Your original code accepted pointer by value, so any modifications to it were lost. It is no different without a thread.

Comment: What are you talking about? Linked lists are a prime example of pointer assignment. There is no "copying pointer by value" except in threads and some STL containers.

Comment: @Maverick What are *you* talking about? Passing a pointer by value always copies the pointer

Comment: When two people with a rep around 30K are telling one person with rep 82 that this person is wrong, it is usually wise for this person to reconsider. However, you can suit yourself.

Comment: _"The only way around that..."_  That's not true.  You could use `std::ref` in the way that **Rinat Veliakhmedov** has shown you in an earlier comment.  (...and **SergeyA** shows in a new answer)

Comment: To those of you moderator-flagging this answer: **don't flag answers just  because you think they are wrong.**  Moderators don't take part in such disputes.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN pointer assignments are pointer assignments and that's a fact. In this case however, assigning a pointer to a new object didn't work and in any other scenario it would have. Consider:
void InitFoo(ClassFoo* ptr) { ptr = new ClassFoo(); ptr->value = 555; }
ClassFoo* foo = null;
InitFoo(foo);
foo->printValue(); // 555

Comment: @Maverick That code snippet invokes *undefined behavior* because you dereference a null-pointer (and on IDEOne it causes a "runtime error": https://ideone.com/Gu0x2F)